# Javascript Date time Coverstion

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, datetime-format

I've date **" 2021-04-04 05:00:00"** in mysql table, in node js when I try to query the record it automatically coverts and returns in **"2021-04-04T09:00:00.000Z"** is there any way to query the date as it is? the thing is the date I've stored in database is already converted UTC time so I don't want this to be converted I'm trying moment and default javascript date nothing works out, anyone can please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use moment.utc() instead of moment().
While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding utc as the timezone when connecting to mysql

```
var db_config = {
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'xxx',
  password : '',
  database : 'xxx',
  timezone: 'utc'  //<- Check this out
};
```